# OpenCV: reading image from std::in?

Tags: c++, opencv, stdin

Is there some way of using OpenCV's `imread` function to read from `std::in`?

```
Mat imread( const string& filename, int flags=1 );
```

Function accepts only filename, but is there some "magic" value for stdin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV provides imdecode functions that work on buffers instead of filename. You would need to read stdin into a buffer first.

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want a very quick hack, here's something that seems to work on Linux:

```
#include <unistd.h>

/* snip */ 

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "/proc/" << getpid() << "/fd/0";

cv::Mat m = cv::imread(ss.str());
```

Comment: Hmm.. that's very hackish. BTW. wouldn't it be easier to use /dev/stdin for that?

Comment: Yeah it would be easier, I was shamefully unaware of that special file:)

Answer (score 0):

No,

But if really you want to, you can stream stdin into a named pipe (mkfifo) and read from it.