# Python-opencv: Read image data from stdin

Tags: python, opencv

How can I read image data from stdin rather than from a file?

With the C++ interface, it seems to be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5458035/908515. The function `imdecode` is available in Python as well. But it expects a `numpy array` as (first) argument. I have no idea how to convert the stdin data.

This is what I tried:

```
import cv
import sys
import numpy

stdin = sys.stdin.read()
im = cv.imdecode(numpy.asarray(stdin), 0)
```

Result: `TypeError: <unknown> data type = 18 is not supported`

Comment: How an image represented in stdin?

Comment: @Igonato: as JPEG data, e.g. `my_program < example.jpeg`. Actually, I'm getting the data from a webcam with another program and I want to avoid creating temporary files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like python stdin buffer is too small for images. You can run your program with `-u` flag in order to remove buffering. More details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3670470/723891) answer.

Second is that `numpy.asarray` probably not right way to get numpy array from the data, `numpy.frombuffer` works for me very well.

So here is working code (only I used `cv2` instead of `cv` hope it wont matter too much):

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy

stdin = sys.stdin.read()
array = numpy.frombuffer(stdin, dtype='uint8')
img = cv2.imdecode(array, 1)
cv2.imshow("window", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Can be executed this way:

```
python -u test.py < cat.jpeg
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not encounter issues with stdin buffering. It is working without `-u`.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for a long time.  Thanks for posting this.  Didn't know of the frombuffer function.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the above solution but could not make it work. Replacing sys.stdin.read() by sys.stdin.buffer.read() did the job:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import cv2

data = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
image = np.frombuffer(data, dtype="uint8")
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imshow('stdin Image',image)
cv2.waitKey()
```